# How can I give path to dotenv file inside Node.js project

Tags: node.js, dotenv

I have the following project structure and I want to use 'dotenv' package to store some values hiding.

```
projectName/src/
projectName/.env/
```

I have two .js file at the moment which are:

```
1. projectName/src/db/mongoose.js :
```

```
const { join } = require('path')
require('dotenv').config({ path: join(__dirname, '..', '..', '.env') })


const connectionURL = process.env.MONGOOSE_CONNECTION_URL
mongoose.connect(connectionURL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
})
```

```
2. projectName/src/index.js :
```

```
const express = require('express')
const { join } = require('path')
require('./db/mongoose')
const User = require('./models/user')

require('dotenv').config({ path: join(__dirname, '..', '.env') })

const app = express()
const port = process.env.NODE_PORT


app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('App is running on port: ' + port);

})
```

since '.env' file is in the root of the project and my project runs from index.js, then why should I always show the path of '.env' file in every other js files?
I think showing the '.env' path in index.js should be enough to run the project.

Answer (score 2):

No you dont have to the right way is that you create config.js file and require dotenv once and put all your config in it and export what you need to use on other files like this.

index.js

```js
const express = require('express')
require('./db/mongoose')
const User = require('./models/user')
const {port} =require('./config')
const app = express()



app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('App is running on port: ' + port);

})
```

config.js

```js
require('dotenv').config({ path:'your .env path' })

module.exports={ port: process.env.NODE_PORT || 5000, connectionURL: process.env.MONGOOSE_CONNECTION_URL }
```

and require it like port in index

Answer (score 1):

Just add `require('dotenv')` in index.js, but at the beginning.
In your example, when you add the db module, dotenv is not configured yet.

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved by calling the

```
require('dotenv').config({ path: join(__dirname, '..', '.env') })
```

before importing the Mongoose file.